# Datatble datetime field is sorted as string

Tags: jquery, django, datatable

I have a Datatble for my django web app, the backend sends date for the field updated as 'Feb. 14, 2023, 3:58 p.m.'. when I use the sorting feature, it always sorts as alphabetical order, where 'April 24, 2023, 10:04 a.m.' comes before Feb because A is bigger than F in alphabetical order, so how to solve this? I tries some from datatble jquery documentation and some StackOverflow answers but it didn't gave me the desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after jquery importing, import momentjs

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

and add this script

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#datatble_id").DataTable({
        columnDefs: [
            {
                targets: [0], // your field position
                type: 'datetime',
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    var momentObj = moment(data, 'MMM. DD, YYYY, h:mm a');
                    if (type === 'sort') {
                        return momentObj.unix();
                    }
                    return momentObj.format('MMM. DD, YYYY, h:mm a');
                },
                orderable: true
            }
        ]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this postgres Code.

use dummy table as

```
create table test (
  datex text
)
```

Insert data

```
insert into test (datex) values ('Feb. 14, 2023, 3:58 p.m.');
insert into test (datex) values ('April 24, 2023, 10:04 a.m.');


select * ,
split_part(datex, ' ', 1),--get Month string
rtrim(split_part(datex, ' ', 2),','),--get day string
rtrim(split_part(datex, ' ', 3),','),--get year string
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(split_part(datex, ' ', 1), 'Mon')),--convert month into number
(rtrim(split_part(datex, ' ', 3),',')||'-'||TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TO_DATE(split_part(datex, ' ', 1), 'Mon')), 'fm00')||'-'||rtrim(split_part(datex, ' ', 2),','))::date as newdat
from test order by newdat
```

> I  split the string using the "split part" function, then converted into the date column.

> After that use "order by" to sort the date column.